# How to query for more than one content_type model from Django LogEntry?

Tags: python, django

I am able to query for one content type mode by doing this:

```
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__model='foo')
```

But what if I want all LogEntry objects that have content_type models `foo` and `bar`?

I tried

```
models_i_want = ['foo', 'bar']
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__model_in=models_i_want)
```

But that fails like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 781, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 799, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1260, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1286, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/opt/sfo/sfo/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1211, in build_filter
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: model_in
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use *double* underscores, so `content_type__model__in=['foo', 'bar']`.

Answer (score 3):

You're super close, you just need to use a double underscore, like this:

```
models_i_want = ['foo', 'bar']
LogEntry.objects.filter(content_type__model__in=models_i_want)
#                                           ^ this is the added _
```

See [Django QuerySet docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) for `in`